# Create PDF from HTML page with formatting retained in PDF in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, html, css, itext

I am trying to convert an HTML page to a PDF using **iTextSharp.dll**  in ASP.Net.

I am able to convert the contents to my PDF , but the problem is that the Formatting of HTML page (which is inline) get removed from my PDF created.

For instance I have the following code block to be formatted from my HTML page to PDF.

```
<table style="width:90%; float:left; background:#dddddd; padding:15px; border:1px solid #000; color:#000;"><tr><td style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">SPECIAL DELIVERY FOR:</td></tr><tr><td style="padding-left:40px; font-size:12px; color:#4e4e4e;">Name: #CustomerName#    
<br /><br /><label>
<b>Date: #CreatedOn#    
</b></label><br />
</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have to format my PDF with much more HTML codes like this.

I have used the Stylesheet class also, but that was not much of help.

Comment: Are you using the deprecated HTMLWorker or the current XMLWorker?

Comment: I am using HTMLWorker in my code.Can I overcome this with XMLWorker ?

Comment: There's a demo you can try here : http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

Answer (score 0):

it might be a better option to convert the html to image and then have itextsharp to  export it to pdf. conversing styles using itextsharp has been very tricky for me and this way makes it a lot easier

Comment: the last time i used itextsharp was in 2010 so they have added additional support since then.